# how to find which table contain record when using union in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I want the table name which contain record when using union in mysql.
I want to delete the records from that table or else i have to go through all tables and find the records and delete manually.

**The query:**

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE cfid='2' 
UNION 
SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE ob_id='2' 
UNION 
SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE jid='2'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.

Comment: well here is sample SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE cfid='2' 
        UNION
        SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE ob_id='2' 
        UNION
        SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE jid='2'  now how i find which table contain the record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include a discriminator column in the individual SELECT statements, with a distinct hardcoded value in each. As an example, we add a column named `src_` to each query ...

```
SELECT '1' AS src_, foo FROM bar WHERE ...

 UNION ALL

SELECT '2' AS src_, grumblestilt FROM skin WHERE ...
```

---

We can use the value returned in that column to determine which SELECT returned a particular row.

Note: if we don't need to eliminate duplicate rows, we can use the `UNION ALL` set operator. The `UNION` operator will go through the work of identifying rows that are duplicates, and eliminating duplicates so we get a result set containing unique tuples.